# How to get notified when I get too far away from my phone?

Tags: alarm

If I am too far from my phone, then it will do no good for the phone alarm to warn me. I may not hear it.

Is there any way to get notified when I get too far away from it?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Please note that device/gadget/peripheral recommendation is off-topic here. You might be interested in our sister site, [HardwareRecs.SE], but please follow [their guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/205) to get a suitable device for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a smart watch. I have been using one for years. One of the many features is a warning when the two go outside the bluetooth range.

I  am using Samsung, but others may also have this function.

Comment: thank you. is there a device that you may know ofm that is simpler than that. maybe a two peice device that one pert sticks to your ohine and the other you carry like on your key ring or in your wallet or purse that will sound alarm if you get to far away such as , say 20 feet away?